# Unresolved symbol error - VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

**h1.h**

```
extern void func_1( int rr );
```

**h1.c**

```
#include < h1.h >
extern void func_1( int rr ){
    int dummy = 32;

    dummy += rr;
}
```

**main.c**

```
int main( void ){
    func_1( 44 );  
}
```

This - as simple as possible - example throws an error:

```
LNK 2019 unresolved symbol func_1
```

It compiles correctly. Do I have to tell the linker where the `.obj` files are?

Comment: In Visual Studio, files with extensions of `.c` are compiled as `C` programs, not C++.

Comment: Why you define the  func_1 as extern ?

Comment: By the way, add line #include < h1.h > in the main.c

Comment: or line extern void func_1( int rr ); :)

Comment: Your main.c does not know where to get the funk_1 function. You have to declarate it or include the declaration.

Comment: @EmbeddedDev -  the h1 is included in main, i lost it somehow when i copied the text.
Thanks for the tip with the file extension, that worked.
I thought the extern is default when you define a function?

Comment: @dagute, extern is used for global function, which defined in other module. It is not default. More info is here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/